after update row level TRIGGER
I am facing issue of recursive trigger. When I run update statement getting error

ORA-04088:error during execution of trigger 'EAMOTAQA.UMA_1_R5EVENTS'.
2.ORA-06512: at "EAMOTAQA.O7RAE", line 34.
3.ORA-06512: at "EAMOTAQA.UMA_1_R5EVENTS", line 45

I write the new trigger for update a column -
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_evt_udfchkbox07
AFTER UPDATE ON r5events
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
IF :NEW.EVT_route IS NOT NULL AND :NEW.evt_udfchkbox07 <> '+' THEN
UPDATE r5events
SET evt_udfchkbox07 = '+'
WHERE  evt_udfchkbox07 <> '+';
END IF;
END;
/
UPDATE r5events
SET evt_udfchkbox07 = '+'
WHERE EVT_route IS NOT NULL;

ORA-04088:error during execution of trigger 'EAMOTAQA.UMA_1_R5EVENTS'.
2.ORA-06512: at "EAMOTAQA.O7RAE", line 34.
3.ORA-06512: at "EAMOTAQA.UMA_1_R5EVENTS"

On the same table trigger UMA_1_R5EVENTS" already exist. So how can I execute the update statement(UPDATE r5events
SET evt_udfchkbox07 = '+'
WHERE EVT_route IS NOT NULL;). Please guide me.
